# How can I get a list of all activity on a file created in Google Drive?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-shared-drive

In the "activity list" of my file stored on Google drive, I see a message "File flagged as containing restricted content". I would like to write a script that goes through the activity list of all files I own, and identifies if any other files have been flagged similarly.

[Screenshot showing Google Drive Activity: File flagged as containing restricted content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsAAX.jpg)

I looked through the the [File Class documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file) for Google App Script (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file ) and did not find anything that looked like it would get Activity details of a file object

I am open to suggestions for finding activity information using Google App Scripts, or other methods if available. Please provide some context if suggesting other methods as I am only familiar with Google App Scripts.

Comment: It looks like the drive api can can list changes: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/